# Implement the Fibonacci sequence... Shifted to the right

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, fibonacci

## Background

We all know the famous [Fibonacci sequence](https://oeis.org/A000045), where each term is the sum of the previous two, with the first term being `0` and the second one being `1`. The first few elements are:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765
```

What we are going to implement today is a similar sequence, starting at `0` and `1` as well, and each term is the sum of the previous two, but *the sum's digits* are shifted by one place to the right. **What does "shifted" mean?** – A digit shifted to the right is basically that digit + 1, unless it equals `9`, which maps to `0` instead. Just as a reference, here is the full list of mappings:

```
0 -> 1;  1 -> 2;  2 -> 3;  3 -> 4;  4 -> 5;  5 -> 6;  6 -> 7;  7 -> 8;  8 -> 9;  9 -> 0
```

---

With all that being said, these are the first terms of our Fibonacci-shifted sequence:

```
0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 22, 30, 63, 4, 78, 93, 282, 486, 879, 2476, 4466, 7053, 22620, 30784, 64515
```

Given an integer **N** (non-negative if 0-indexed and positive if 1-indexed), finds the **N**th term of the Fibonacci-shifted sequence.

## Rules

- The output may contain leading zero(es), in case `9` is the first (few) digit(s).
- Input and output can be handled using any **[default mean](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)**.
- Take note that **[Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)** are forbidden.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), hence your program will be scored in bytes, with *less* bytes being better.

Comment: A useless sequence that's **not** on OEIS..?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Exactly.

Comment: On reflection, this should be a duplicate of Fibonacci... it's literally just `digit + 1 mod 10` for each digit after the sum is performed. I have a hammer so I'm not voting, yet.

Comment: I'd agree with you (though I also have a hammer)

Comment: @ConorO'Brien I'd agree too...also have hammer.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien "Hammered" it myself.

Comment: Rotating the sum's digits left has a period of 59.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>78</s> 72 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n>1and int(''.join(`-~int(i)%10`for i in`f(n-1)+f(n-2)`))or n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsMwDAS/okuJROsS@RhIPxICUknduiSyMbnk0q@7zmmZmc3H/knmaw3jqttzUbDBHqy2QLQdu@7@TdFQ3O/ESBfuJaQCsWUJaI7peo4nIWreai7tCbJpxnCDovZ@oe@JZOLB8Vz/)

Saved 6 bytes thanks to Halvard Hummel.

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsMwDAS/okuJROsS@RhIPxICUknduiSyMbnk0q@7zmmZmc3H/knmaw3jqttzUbDBHqy2QLQdu@7@TdFQ3O/ESBfuJaQCsWUJaI7peo4nIWreai7tCbJpxnCDovZ@oe@JZOLB8Vz/)

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG! Great first answer! Also, mind if I ask whether you have anything to do with [this user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44713/votetoclose)?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I don't know them, but my name was inspired by theirs. Is that a problem? **EDIT**: Never mind, might as well change my name.

Comment: @VoteToReopen No, that is not a problem. I was just asking out of cheer curiosity :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ð+D‘%⁵Ḍø¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//w7ArROKAmCXigbXhuIzDuMKh//81)

-2 thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis).

Explanation:

```
ð+D‘%⁵Ḍø¡ Full program. Takes input through STDIN.
ð         Start new dyadic chain
 +        Add the left (f(n - 1)) and right (f(n - 2)) arguments
  D       Get list of decimal digits
   ‘      Increment each
    %⁵    Modulo ⁵ (10)
      Ḍ   Convert from decimal to integer
       ø  Start new niladic chain
        ¡ Repeat previous chain z times (where z is taken from STDIN as there are no arguments)
```

Comment: This is a repost of my answer on the old deleted question.

Comment: If you take input from STDIN, you can eliminate both `0`.

Comment: @Dennis I was expecting Jelly-related action of yours after seeing your comment :p **EDIT**: There *was* a comment on the question that now got deleted.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>63</s> 62 bytes

This is what I'd come up with before the challenge was deleted, don't have time to golf it further now.

Returns the `n`th number in the sequence, 0-indexed.

```
f=(n,x=0,y=1)=>n?f(--n,y,+[...x+y+""].map(z=>++z%10).join``):x
```

- 1 byte saved thanks to Conor.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LcxhCsIgGADQuwyCT3Ti@hm42DkqUpaGtn2KRugub0Ud4D2vXzrPycVnn6O7mbQGfJjampWArEjBqhyIHPFooe@RVUZPnPNCK@26C191hE2OlG67QRDug0OlyKG0OWAOi@FLuMMXTCnpCntBfgauzH9WC5781RkVaW8)

---

### Alternative, 55 bytes

A quick port of VoteToReopen's excellent Python solution.

```
f=n=>n>1?+[...f(--n)+f(--n)+""].map(x=>++x%10).join``:n
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##LcvRCsIgFADQfxkE92Jeth4Djb6jImVpaNtVNGL7eiPa03k60X5sHUvIb1lzeLgyJ365tTWvWGnWw0lciMiDlIxio@tuNNsMi9JCLLuhR4opsDFHbmPimiZHU3rCb55LsSscevwXuO8jKu0h4paubLB9AQ)

Comment: -1 byte: change `~~` to `+`

Comment: Oh, yeah. Thanks, @ConorO'Brien; the `~~` snuck back in there when I rewrote this on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
[`(-&2(10|>:)&.(10&#.inv)@+&$:<:)@.(1&<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6zkE@bv@jEzR01Yw0DA1q7Kw01fSADDVlvcy8Mk0HbTUVKxsrTQegmJqN5n9NrpLU4hKQGanJGfkOGkDzQIapK@jaAYms/My84pKizLx0hVgFazUlK4U0iAYlA4VMPSOD/wA)

Highlighted following is the standard Fibonacci husk:

```
[`(-&2                    +&$:<:)@.(1&<)
```

Then, we compose the following function with the result of adding the previous two terms:

```
      (10|>:)&.(10&#.inv)@
```

This, in turn, is the function `10|>:` atop `10&#.inv`, which gets the digits of a number. That is to say, the digits are obtained, then the function `10|>:` is applied, then the digits are combined to make a number again. `10|>:` is a fork that is equivalent to `(y + 1) % 10` in a conventional language for input `y`.